# Creating a layered line plot that highlights a few choices by default and then highlights based on mouseover and makes every other line grey

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I want to highlight the line on which the mouse is hovering. Along with that, I also want to display some lines in color when no user interaction through mouse has taken place. But I want those lines to turn grey when the user starts interacting.

Is it possible as of now, in Altair / Vega-Lite?

I have gotten close, using the layering technique, I highlight the selected line on top of all and I am also able to display some default lines with colors. It's the greying of those *initially colored lines* that I am failing to do -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3 ,1,2,3], 'fruit': ['apple','apple','apple','orange','orange','orange','peach','peach','peach', 'banana','banana','banana', 'mango', 'mango', 'mango'], 'price': [4,8,12, 1,2,4, 5,7,9, 1,2,3, 4,10, 15]})

highlight = alt.selection_single(on='mouseover',fields=['fruit'], nearest=True, empty='none')

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='time:O',
    y='price:Q',
    detail='fruit',
    color = alt.value('lightgrey')
)

background = base.mark_line().encode(
    color=alt.condition(alt.datum.fruit == 'mango', alt.value('green'), alt.value('yellow'))
).transform_filter({'thatfield': 'fruit', 'oneOf': ['apple', 'mango']})

# middleground = base.mark_line().encode(
#     color=alt.condition(highlight, alt.value('red'), alt.value('lightgrey'))
# )

foreground = base.mark_line().encode(
    color=alt.value('red')
).transform_filter(highlight)

points = base.mark_circle().encode(
    opacity=alt.value(0)
).add_selection(
    highlight
)

points+base+background+foreground
```

When mouse is outside the area, it looks fine -
[image]

When mouse is near a line, it highlights the line, but the issue is that the **default** lines do not become **grey** -
[image]

To achieve that, I tried using **middleground** (the idea being, whatever is selected is *red*, otherwise *grey*, superimposed on default values) that you can see commented in the code, but since it is layered on top of *background*, the default colors get hidden and become *grey* right from the start.
[image]

Any suggestions?